# Correct site for SaaS tools

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm going to be stringing a bunch of cloud [SaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) tools together (is that redundant?) to create an automation solution, and will have a bunch of questions. Is the correct site Stack Overflow? Or Super User? or is there a special one for SaaS (I couldn't find one...)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to ask [SaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) questions on [a few](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/282094) of our sites. Stack Overflow is for programming.

Super User only has [8 questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/saas). Webmasters [has 13](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saas), but [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/saas) has 63; so there's a bigger audience there, **if** your question is on-topic for the site.